# React-slick carousel with custom pagging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, carousel, react-slick

- Am trying to implement a carousel with a react-slick and i want to have thumbnails which i have tried to implement with react-slick custom paging.
- Am fetching data from dummyJson Api, am only interested in displaying
- Below is how am fetching data

```
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let path = "https://dummyjson.com/products/1"
        axios.get(path)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setProduct(res.products)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])
```

- Below is the carousel component

```
    const settings = {
        customPaging: function (i) {
            return (
                <a href='#/'>
                    <img src={image[i + 1].images} alt='kt' /> ###this line is where am getting the problem i think
                </a>

            );
        },
        dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
        infinite: false,
        dots: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 500,
        lazyLoad: 'progressive',
        initialSlide: 1
    };
```

Here is how i want to populate the images in the app

```
                                    <Slider {...settings}>
                                        {product.?images?.map(item => (
                                            <div key={item.id}>
                                                <img src={item} alt='gh' />
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </Slider>
```

- The data is being fetched from the database with images but the images are not being displayed.
- Any assistance will be appreciated